# compression techniques supported by solr, I want to use compression techniques which supported by solr on solr indexed data

Tags: hadoop, solr, compression

I want to use compression techniques which supported by solr on solr indexed data. 
Any suggestions on this aspects.

Comment: You'll have to expand the question in relation to what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and what the issues were (and why you're looking into compression in the first place). Have you looked at the [codec factory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Codec+Factory) page in the Solr reference guide?

Comment: Indexed data is already transformed into a very compact form (posting list). Did you mean to say you want to compress stored data? Why? The use case is not clear.

Comment: hi Alexandre , i want to compress the stored data which was indexed by solr engine.